# How to Change Android Nougat Notification Inline Reply Color?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat

Android 7.0 Nougat brings new inline notifications - the ability to reply to messages from within the notification. I would like to know how to change the inline reply background and highlight color. 
[image: New Nougat Notification Nook]

Playing around a bit, I have discovered that the background color is dependent upon your colorPrimary. The highlight color is then generated from the Primary Color. Unfortunately, the background color is NOT colorPrimary. It is much darker than the primary color.

Color Primary:

[image: Color Primary]

Inline Color:

[image]

Is it possible to override the default background color and highlight color?

Answer (score 1):

Try setColor when you create NotificationCompat.Builder